# Today I've updated a Mac mini and it won't boot even to recovery mode

Tags: macos, recovery, data-recovery

Monitor is switching between being black and turned off. The same when starting with Cmd-R. I clicked update, rebooted computer, and this happened. What can I do? I was updating to newest El Captain, probably, as I already had quite fresh version of it.

Comment: Is your system backed up, e.g using Time Machine? Do you have access to another Mac and an 8 GB USB Flash Drive in which you can make an OS X USB Installer?

Comment: @user3439894: thanks for the information about possibility of making an installer. I should probably make a one for a sake anyway, yes? My issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

After I disconnected power for a longer time (to get the serial number), ~25 minutes, the system started to recovery console, and then started normally. I did SMC reset via 15 second unplug, but apparently this was not enough.